# Using query as a text join

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, text

A few days ago I reach the limit of 50000 characters in one cell, I found a solution with "query" but I need a delimiter inside the formula that I haven't been able to find:

This is the formula:

```
=arrayformula(query(Sort!A2:A,,10000000))
```

as an example I used this A, B and C

with `=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,arrayformula(A2:A))` I get:

```
A|B|C
```

but with `=arrayformula(query(A2:A,,10000000))` I get:

```
A B C
```

How can I make the delimiter?

Comment: Might be valuable to explain why you need text strings with >50,000 characters in your cells.  Might be an [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) that we can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexreplace()` and `substitute()` with [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465) like this:

`=arrayformula( regexreplace( substitute( substitute( query( substitute(A2:A, " ", "µ"), "", 9^9), " ", "|" ), "µ", " " ), "\|+$", "" ) )`

If your data does not contain spaces, you can leave out the inner and outer `substitute()`.